# Robot class paste issue to putty terminal

Tags: java, ssh, putty, awtrobot

I am trying to paste a string to putty command prompt by using a java program by using the `Robot` class.

In order to paste, I have to press `shift` + `insert` key.What I am trying to do is paste the String "HelloWorld" to putty command prompt. Following is my code.

```
package Auto;

//Related imports

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AWTException {

        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p;

        String username = "ABC";
        String password = "DEF";
        String serverString = "100.0.0.0";

        String s = "C:\\Users\\ib\\Desktop\\Putty\\putty.exe -ssh -l " + username + " -pw " + password + " "
                + serverString + "";
        try {

            p = r.exec(s);

            Thread.sleep(3000);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        String text = "HelloWorld"; 
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(text); 
        Clipboard clipboard=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents(stringSelection,stringSelection);

        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        Thread.sleep(150);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_INSERT); 
    }
}
```

This code presses the `shift` button but does not press the `insert` button. Could someone please point out what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is with `keyPress`? E.g. can you paste into notepad using `ctrl-v`? Or perhaps the Putty window doesn't have input focus?

Comment: Hi @user234461. I tried with notepad. Its a problem with keyPress. Shift button is pressed but not the insert.

Comment: Can you make `Robot` press `insert` with a different program in focus?

Comment: BTW, you might try pressing `KeyEvent.VK_PASTE`, too...

Comment: Hi @UsagiMiyamoto yes. Tried that as well but did not work.